# Android Repeating Alarm invoking a service

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to send GPS coordinates to server in every 1 minute interval through a background service . It invokes the service for thee first time but it doesn't repeat it .

Code for setting the alarm:

```
Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(CheckInActivity.this, GoogleMapService.class);
                    gpsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(CheckInActivity.this, 0, gpsIntent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager_gps = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    Calendar calendar_gps = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar_gps.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
                    alarmManager_gps.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_gps.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), gpsPendingIntent);
```

Service

```
    public class GoogleMapService extends Service {

private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;
private static Location sLocation;   
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
private CallBack callback;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.w(null,"GPS Service called");
    locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
    if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }

    callback = new CallBack() {

        public void onResult(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProgress() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {       
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            // This needs to stop getting the location data and save the battery power.
            locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
            sLocation = location;
            Model.coordinates = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
            try{
                SendGPSCoordinatesOperation task = new SendGPSCoordinatesOperation(callback);
                task.execute("");
                Log.w(null,"Sent");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.w(null,"Couldn't be sent");
            }
            Log.w(null,"The coordinates are"+Model.coordinates);
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

}
```

EDIT : AndroidManifest code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
private void setLocationSendingAlarm() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleMapService.class);
        intent.putExtra("locationSendingAlarm", true);
        PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 987654321, intent,0);
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        int timeForAlarm=60000;


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+timeForAlarm, timeForAlarm,pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Call this method in onCreate() of service and this will work.I am using same code to send location in my app.And this is working fine for me and one more correction-- change timeForAlarm=1000  to timeForAlarm=60000;

Answer (score 0):

```
gpsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(CheckInActivity.this, 0, gpsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: No effect . Same as before .For the first time it sends . Doesn't trigger the alarm subsequently.

Comment: Try to set "60000" instead of TimeUnit. Strange though, because FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will allow repeating of alarm.

Comment: Did you log inside onCreate of your Service? and added android:enabled="true" to your Service in the Manifest?

Comment: Yes I did . By the way for a service i believed enabled attribute is by default true .Anyways I tried that as well . Didn't work .

Comment: Really strange :S you're sure you're not doing anything else that causes the alarm to break? Otherwise I really don't know.

Comment: Don't really know why it wasn't working . But thanks for the reply