# AlarmManager Does Not Start Service

Tags: java, android, service, calendar, alarmmanager

I've built an application which is supposed to send an SMS containing data usage at specified intervals - once when the application is first launched - then again once every minute (this has been shortened to one minute simply for testing purposes) however only the inital sms is sent so it seems the alarm is never expiring and launching my intent.

P.S.

After extensive testing with CodeMagic - we still cannot get the Alarm to expire and launch the service.

Any suggestions?

SOURCE:

```
public class WifiMonitor extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    private Date myDate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);


        // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
        double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
        totalBytes /= 1000000;
        mobileBytes /= 1000000;
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
        String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
        String info = String.format(
                "Wifi Data Usage: %s MB\tMobile Data Usage: %s MB", totalStr,
                mobileStr);
        infoView.setText(info);

        // send traffic info via sms
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, info, null, null);
        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

        // get the current date
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // convert the date to milliseconds
        long millis = date.getTime();

        // save the date to shared preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
    }

    // set the alarm to expire 30 days from the date stored in sharePreferences


    public void invokeAlarm(long invokeTime, long rowId) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(myDate);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Alarm.class);
        i.putExtra("rowId", String.valueOf(rowId));
        long waitTime = 1000*10*1;
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime, PendingIntent.getService(
                        this, 0, i, 0));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime, pi);


    }

}
```

ALARM:

```
public class Alarm extends Service {


    // compat to support older devices
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        onStartCommand(intent, 0, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // check to ensure everything is functioning

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Usage Sent", 2000);
        toast.show();

        // send SMS
        String sms = "";
        sms += ("\tWifi Data Usage: "
                + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                        .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()))
                / 1000000 + " MB");

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, sms, null, null);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Method Attempted after codeMagic's most recent response:

```
    // set the alarm to execute the service

    public void invokeAlarm(long invokeTime, long rowId) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(myDate);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alarm.class);
        i.putExtra("rowId", String.valueOf(rowId));
        long waitTime = 1000 * 10 * 1;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime,
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        try {
            am.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        int timeForAlarm=10000;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+timeForAlarm, timeForAlarm,pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)) instead of `set()`?

Comment: What is the advantage?

Comment: `setRepeating()` runs the `AlarmManager` for the given interval. Maybe  I missed something, but as it stands I don't see where you are telling it to run every minute

Comment: cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        invokeAlarm(cal.getTimeInMillis(), rowId);

...is where I'm attempting to specify the interval - but this may be where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I accidentally edited yours instead of mine but changed it back. Try what I have now in the last line

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, PendingIntent.getService(
            this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0));
```

to

```
long waitTime = 1000*60*1
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime PendingIntent.getService(
            this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0));
```

`cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);` just adds 1 minute to the current `cal` value. And I'm not sure there's any reason to call `invokeAlarm()` within itself unless I am totally missing something you are doing

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime, PendingIntent.getService(
        this, 0, i, 0));
```

You may also need to create the `PendingIntent` to use in the `am`

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime, pi);
```

Comment: When I did it caused 2 new errors: 

Syntax error on token "PendingIntent", delete this token
Cannot invoke getService(WifiMonitor, int, Intent, int) on the primitive type long

Comment: Change `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` to an `int` instead of trying to cast. Just try using 0

Comment: Does this look correct? 

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime PendingIntent.getService(
    this, int, 0);

Comment: Change `PendingIntent.getService( this, int, 0);` to `PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, i, 0);`

Comment: So I changed it to:


am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, i, 0);

but ended up with:



The method setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent) in the type AlarmManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, long, long)
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

Comment: So I changed it to this:

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, waitTime); PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, i, 0);

and I'm still getting this error:

The method setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent) in the type AlarmManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, long, long)

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you... (I'm just trying to get this up and running - I appreciate your help!)

Comment: Try my edit...its hard to see in comments. It will be a few before I can check back.You need to replace the first semicolon in the statement with a comma

Comment: I updated my source as suggested. (Still running into two errors: "Syntax error on token "PendingIntent", delete this token" and "Cannot invoke getService(WifiMonitor, int, Intent, int) on the primitive type long")

Comment: Thanks for your help...It's compiling with no errors! (But it still doesn't send the sms every 60 seconds - only when the app is first opened - it appears the alarm still isn't working)

Comment: (...and yes - I changed it back to an actual working phone number) : )

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? Do you set a breakpoint at `onStart()` to verify it doesn't run? You can try adding this function to the service and calling it also in `onCreate()` of `Service` as [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160377/android-repeating-alarm-invoking-a-service) suggest. Other than that, I'm not sure what's wrong at this point

Comment: I haven't checked just yet but I have a Toast which is supposed to appear - and I've run adb shell dumpsys alarm to see if I could find the alarm... but I'm getting back so much data it's actually cut off and won't let me scroll up anymore. Do you know of a method to just find the Alarm I'm looking for?

Comment: The best way is to set a breakpoint in your `Service` and see if the code ever runs again. `Toasts` work to but breakpoints are generally the best way, IMHO

Comment: Also - could it be due to the fact there is no reference to startId in WifiMonitor.java ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not sure what the problem is at this point and there's been too many edits. Also, you shouldn't change your OP. It was better off with the edits or it gets confusing and useless for others. Maybe since we have it compiling you should post a new question so it won't be so cluttered and easier for others to sift through. I can try to look at it more later. Last thing, did you try following the answer I posted in my comment?

Comment: I tried posting a new question... it got deleted (moderators thought it was a duplicate post) 

Was the answer you mentioned setting a breakpoint? (If so - then yes.)

Comment: No, [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160377/android-repeating-alarm-invoking-a-service)

Comment: Updated using the method suggested - still not starting : (